# Review Post Count Issue

Tags: discussion

At the top toolbar, it is showing 4 items to be reviewed but actually there are no items are pending to be reviewed.

Is this an issue in counting?

[image: Review post]

Comment: Similar: https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2173/posts-awaiting-review-broken

Comment: They are rolling out a new top bar soon so maybe that will be fixed? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300829/new-top-bar-is-coming-to-the-stack-exchange-network?cb=1